# xmap is not creating sitemap correctly

Tags: joomla, sitemap

Although I've plenty of categories(60 in total) for my site: http://www.downloadformsindia.com, xmap joomla module does not seem to show proper sitemap structure- it's showing only main menu items only.
What could be the problem?

For example every state listed in this page : http://www.downloadformsindia.com/select-the-state-to-download-the-form.html is a category in itself, but ignored by xmap in sitemap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default xmap only looks at the menu items, not categories and sections. There are lots of extensions for xmap out there. Perhaps you need to configure one of these?

Comment: What do you mean by "There are lots of extensions for xmap out there." Are you saying I should try other extensions?

Comment: xmap wont map sections and categories unless specifically told to do so, look in the extensions area of xmap within Joomla.